# Java - Object is not being set?

Tags: java

Consider the following code, attempting to add a `Product` object into a `productList`, which is an array of the type `Product[]`.

```
public void addItem(Product product) {

    for (Product p : productList) {
        if (p != null){
            p = product;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(productList[0]);  // This yields null.

}
```

Like commented, the print results in `null`. Why is the product not being set?

Update: I've ran debug-printouts inside the `!= null` clause, and both the object and the rest of the clause is run properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your for-each-loop the variable `p` is a temporary variable to which the contents of `productList` will be assigned. Thus you are always just assigning the temporary variable instead of to the items inside the list.

You probably want this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < productList.length; i++)
{
    if (productList[i] == null)
    {
        productList[i] = product;
        break;
    }
}
```

Without the `break` you would assign `product` to **every** item that is `null` (actually it would be better to use `boolean`s to handle the loop break but this works, too)

Comment: Additionally, I'd assume `addItem()` would want to stick `product` in the first *empty* slot in `productList`. So it should really be `p == null`.

Comment: Yeah, my apologies for the typos. The code was just a quick toss-together to present the problem, not the actual code, just tried to make it more readable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the for-each loop, also known as the "enhanced" for loop, to set array variables since it uses a temp variable inside of the loop. You can use it to change the state of an object already held by the array since the temp variable will refer to the same object, but not to set the reference itself. Solution: use a standard for loop.

From the Java Language Specification, [§14.14.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2):

> The enhanced for statement is equivalent to a basic for statement of
> the form:
>
> ```
> for (I #i = Expression.iterator(); #i.hasNext(); ) {
>     VariableModifiersopt TargetType Identifier =
>         (TargetType) #i.next();
>     Statement
> }
> ```

So in your case, loosely:

```
for (int n; n < productList.length; ++n) {
    Product p = productList[n];
    if (p != null) {
        p = product;
    }
}
```

From that, you can see why `productList[0]` is never set. `p` is set, for the duration of that loop iteration, but never `productList[0]`.